# Apache Mod Rewrite - Last parameter only?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite some URL's based only on the last parameter.  For example:

```
http://www.site.com/some-param/some-param/THIS-param
```

I want to grab `THIS-param` and use that for the rewrite. It always be the last parameter, but not necessarily the 3rd.  Could be 2nd, 3rd, 4th, or 5th.

Im getting close with this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ index.php?url_title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

using this as the url (for example).

```
http://www.test.com/param1
```

The problem is, once I add 'param2' the site stops working.  I think it's cause param1 appear to be a directory.

```
http://www.test.com/param1/param2
```

Any idea why?  Here's my full set of rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ index.php?url_title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had it. You need to capture everything that comes after the last `/`, and optionally capture what comes before it if needed. You said it coudld be 2nd through 5th, but didn't mention 1st, so that assumes *something* comes before it with a `/`, as in `^.+/`.

This also allows for a trailing `/`

#### Edited to incorporate existing rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Real existing files not rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#Inelegant hack to permit one param only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url_title=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^.+/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url_title=$1 [L,QSA]
# Anything not matching above goes to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hey Michael, this doesn't seem to be working still.  See my original original question where I've posted my full .htaccess file.  I'm only using the .htaccess for this, so any useless rules, or possibly conflicting ones, can be removed

Comment: Hey Michael, this seems to be working, except with one parameter it doesn't.  Sorry about the 2nd through 5th, I meant that more as, it could have any number of parameters

Comment: Oh, think I figured it out, just removed the `^.+/` from the beginning of the rule.  So I think everything is working now.  However, it seems all of the javascript functionality and stylesheet rules go away after there's more than one parameter.  But the htaccess part seems to be working, so thanks!

Comment: @dtj Hack added above. should work but if I think of a more elegant way I will update it later.